# Google Protocol Buffers. C++ error: ‘google’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get the following simple C++ program to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using google::protobuf;

int main(void){
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

> error: ‘google’ has not been declared

I've linked to -lproto and have `protobuf-compiler` and `libprotobuf-dev` installed.

I'm totally stuck now.

Anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: you are missing some header files that has namespace 'google' defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't include any header which declares the `google` namespace. You should include the header file generated by the `protoc` compiler; it pulls in the necessary includes.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the header for Protocol Buffers, so the `google` namespace is not declared.

Comment: Include the header file that the protobuf compiler generated.

Comment: A diagram would be great, thnx

Comment: @Iarsmans. I got it all working now... `using namespace google::protobuf;` I feel like such a noob...